# generate dynamically binary fields/get access to the related fields in the view

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Odoo 11.0, community edition.

1) I have order and order_line, which is associated with several items. I want to generate for every product file/s (delivery label) but the problem is that I don't know how many products would be associated with one order. Can I somehow dynamically create binary fields and store the files there, based on the length of order_lines  or I need prepare firstly some quantity of fields, like Label1, Label2,Label3 etc. and only this schema will work?

2) I want also to show in the sale.view_order_form, on separate page, the name and the price of related product:

```
test = fields.Char(related="order_line.product_id.name", string="Name")
```

this line works fine and I can see the name of product, but it shows only the first product name. In case if the order has 2-3 products, I can't get access to them. What would be the best way to show related fields of order_line in this case?

```
test = fields.Char(related="order_line[0].product_id.name", string="Name")

test2 = fields.Char(related="order_line[1].product_id.name", string="Name2")
```

(it doesn't work and I'd like to avoid hard-coding)

Thanks in advance for any advise regarding these questions.

Comment: Seems that you are trying to do things that aren't correctly designed, not a proper solution. Maybe you could explain better your needs to be able to receive a way to solve it

Comment: Sure, thanks. I want to allow users to generate delivery label  by clicking on the button "generate label" on order level. When someone clicks into the button, API request is done and it returns binary data, which I save in Binary field. For every product within order should be done separate request with different dimensions like: size, height etc. and the problem is that I don't know how many products could be associated with the order but I need to prepare some binary fields, where I could store these labels.

Comment: Add the binary field to the order_line model. To display product names on order level use compute field.

Comment: Great, thanks Tedaeusz, actually I already did the same but associated it with Order Level instead of Order Line (will double check, maybe Order Line is better idea).